# Getting the checkbox values from Last selected using JavaScript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, jquery-events

I am  having a set of checkboxes which allows multiple checking. And I want to get the values by the last selected one.  for example consider 4 checkboxes with values 1, 2, 3, 4. If I select 4, 2, 1 i need the values [4,2,1] as I selected instead of getting [1,2,4]

this is my html code snippet

```
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup" value="1"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup" value="2"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup" value="3"></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup" value="4"></li>
```

the code below is my JQuery script to get the values in a array

```
var arr = $.map($('.checkGroup:checked'), function(e, i) {                
                value = e.value;
                return value;
            });
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: If you are getting `1,2,4` in `arr` you can use `arr.reverse()`.

Comment: @Manwal it can be selected in order or `2,4,1` it will still get `1,2,4`.

Comment: No not like that. If I select  `[4,1,2]` i m getting `[1,2,4]`. if i use `reverse()` i would get `[4,2,1]`. But i need `[4,1,2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var selectedArr = [];
var dataElem = $('#data');
$('.checkGroup').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    selectedArr.push(this.value);
  } else {
    selectedArr.splice(selectedArr.indexOf(this.value), 1);
  }

  dataElem.html(JSON.stringify(selectedArr));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"></div>
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup" value="1">
</li>
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup" value="2">
</li>
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup" value="3">
</li>
<li>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup" value="4">
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to store the array values as and when you are updating the state like

```js
var arr = [];
$('.checkGroup').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    arr.unshift(this.value)
  } else {
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(this.value), 1);
  }
});

$('button').click(function() {
  snippet.log(arr.join(', '))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup" value="1"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup" value="2"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup" value="3"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="checkGroup" value="4"></li>
</ul>
<button>Print</button>
```

Comment: can you give the case that is not working... and the expected result

Comment: @ArunPJohny, `push` instead of `unshift` ?